# Multidimensional display array values

Tags: twig

I have an array:

```
Array ( 
    [author] => Array ( 
        [0] => john 
        [1] => smith 
    )
    [description] => Array ( 
        [0] => lorum ipsum 
        [1] => lorum ipsum 
    ) 
)
```

How to display array in a row containing values `author[0]` and `description[0]`, `author[1]` and `description[1]` 
using twig template

Comment: `{{ my_array['author'][0] }}`

Comment: its not working

Comment: @annaraiders "It's not working" is something a user would say. Can you tell us what isn't working. Have you got twig setup correctly?

Comment: @RichardHousham I tried the above code it is not working, In {% for myarray in my_array %} {{ myarray['author'][0] }} {% endfor %} it doesn't work . if you use myarray.0 it is showing the value. sorry i am new to twig.

Comment: try {% for myar in my_array %} {{ dump(myar ) }} {% endfor %}
Paste the output into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data are not properly structured. If you really need to iterate over this dataset, you can use something like this one:

```
{% for key, author in my_array.author %}
    {{ author }} {{ my_array.description[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```